# Подскажите, почему не находит запись?

Tags: php, mysqli

Пытаясь вывести из таблицы базы данных столбец на страницу, не выводится ничего! Как с этим быть?

```
$proj_id = $address_mysqli->query("SELECT `project_id` FROM `projects`");
$row = $proj_id->fetch_array();

echo $row['project_id'];
```

Comment: Проверяйте, что выводит `var_dump($row);`

Comment: `fetch_array` скорее всего возвращает индексированный от 0 массив, вам нужен `fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @And, `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["project_id"]=> string(1) "1" }` вот что выводит.

Comment: @u_mulder, опять же ничего не выводит.

Comment: Ну должно значит работать.

Comment: @And, но он всё равно ничего не выводит. Либо выводит пустоту, я так и не понял. Хотя в таблице записи есть.

Comment: Если `var_dump` выводит, как вы показали выше, все обязано работать. Метод `fetch_array`, по умолчанию выводит в оба массива - обычный и ассоциативный, ибо по умолчанию стоит в его аргументе `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Comment: @And, у меня ничего не выводит. Ни ошибки, ни данных. Значит мне надо искать проблему в базе данных, а не в коде?

Comment: Так вы же показываете вывод `var_dump`, откуда вы тогда это взяли?\

Comment: @And, объясните по подробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: @Вячеслав, к сожалению мы с трудом понимаем, что у вас там происходит. Ибо ранее не встречал такого, чтобы `var_dump` возвращал, а обращение по индексу к массиву, выдавал предупреждение о его не существовании. Это какой-то бред. Ну попробуйте `echo $row[0];`. Тоже `Notice` выдаст?

Comment: Вангую: в `echo $row['project_id'];` присутствует _не латинская буква_ в строковом литерале индекса. Либо 'o', либо 'e', либо 'p', либо 'c'. Простейший способ решения - скопипастить строку индексного значения из вывода var_dump'а.

Answer (score -2):

Я с этим столкнулся когда делал свой учебный варезник на чистом `PHP`.
Вот в чём суть.

После выборки данных - этот массив нужно обработать и сформировать другой массив при помощи цикла.
Вот так:

```
while( $row = $proj_id->fetch_array() ){
  $items[] = $row;
}
```

А использовать уже сформированный массив `$items`, предварительно протестировав его `var_dump($items);` - чтоб понять, сработал ли код вообще...

Comment: К сожалению выдаёт это **Notice: Undefined index: project_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectboard\project.php on line 13**.
А так же, при тесте выдаёт это _array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["project_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["project_id"]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["project_id"]=> string(1) "3" } }_.
Можете пожалуйста подсказать, я вообще хочу сделать динамическую страницу по этому id, который задаётся как первичный ключ. Но _$_GET['project_id']_ ничего не даёт. Решил проверить так. Откуда он его берёт. Видимо ниоткуда

Comment: Надеюсь не поздно отвечаю! var_dump() - показал: у Вас получилось сформировать запрос и принять ответ из БД, а так же сформировать двумерный массив. Попробуйте сделать: fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Дальше! Чтоб из этого сформировать запрос GET! Я знаю только 1 способ: header("Location: http://ваш-сайт//index.php?project_id={$items['project_id']}"); - Это примерно так (Это перезагрузит страницу с отправкой GET['project_id'] )... Останется только принять $_GET['project_id']... Но если: echo $items["project_id"] - не работает, то и header не сработает.

Comment: Я, с трудом понимаю, что и зачем так делать, конструкция получается очень шаткая и малопонятная... Брать из БД какой-то id, не отфильтровав его - использовать для запроса с GET... Зачем! Но если надо стало я ответил выше... и...
Вот ссылки на документацию, что я использовал:
1) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php 
2) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: ,можете пожалуйста подсказать как тогда следует действовать? Я хотел формировать по project_id страницу определённого проекта, куда бы отправлял все данные проекта связанные с этим ID. Но столкнулся с тем, что даже не могу отловить этот project_id.

Comment: Очень много писать, поэтому ответил в другом сообщении! Удачи!
А если просто нужно отловить из получившегося массива результат то можно воспользоваться: echo $items[0]['project_id']; - массив двумерный.

Comment: `можно воспользоваться: echo $items[0]['project_id'];` - вы это сейчас серьезно? Там не многомерный массив, а всего лишь 2х мерный.  Хоспди, да прочитайте же вы наконец, про функцию `fetch_array`.

Answer (score -2):

Кажется я понял примерно (из доп сообщений). Нужно взять конкретный id из БД-1; послать запрос на выборку в БД-2 строки по этому id(из БД-1). Результаты - отрисовать на отдельной странице. *Я бы посоветовал скачать с торрентов курсик по PHP (Игоря Борисова, например)...*

**А если кратко:** нужен **ассоциативный** массив (для "отлова" project_id). Если использовать **двумерный** массив, как тут - будет намного сложнее...

**Чтоб отловить:**

1. Кидаем наш массив в foreach, с проверкой по ключу ЕСЛИ ключ ==
   project_id - записываем в отдельную переменную и прерываем
   директивой break; ЭНАЧЕ прерываем директивой continue;
2. Эту переменную используем для sql запроса по id в "нужную" БД-2... Так же получая ассоциативный массив.
3. Отрисовываем на "нужной" странице массив при помощи foreach...

```html
while( $row = $proj_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
 $items[] = $row;
  }
  
  //Массив $items в foreach
  
  foreach ($items as $key => $itemid){
 if ($key == 'project_id'){
   $id_sql = $itemid; //Вот мы уже поймали нужный id если задача в этом стояла
   break;
  } else {
   continue;
  }
  
  //Но как я увидел из var_dump - у вас целых 3 разных записи по одному ключу 'project_id'... Мой цикл возьмёт первый и прервётся
  //Формируем новый запрос по id, используя $id_sql ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО АССОЦИАТИВНЫЙ такой код с циклом ( $row = $НОВАЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )... и получаем такой же массив но из другой БД-2 
  //Отрисуем на странице по примеру ЭТОГО МАССИВА из БД-1...
  //Смотря сколько эл-тов (ключей) массива столько и строк:
  foreach ($Новый_массив as $item){?>
 <p><? echo $item['сюда вставить нужный ключь']; ?></p>
 <p><? echo $item['сюда вставить нужный ключь']; ?></p>
 <p><? echo $item['сюда вставить нужный ключь']; ?></p>
 <p><? echo $item['сюда вставить нужный ключь']; ?></p>
  <?}

//Сделал "с закрытыми глазами", работоспособность не проверял)) Но у меня подобное работало! УДАЧИ!
```

Comment: Это типо вы блеснули умом? А ничего, что `fetch_array` по умолчанию возвращает и ассоциативный и обычный массив? Да ко всему прочему, раз реально нужен ассоциативный массив, без костыльного `fetch_array`, лучше использовать `fetch_assoc()`. Но суть то не в этом, а в том, что `var_dump` возвращает массив, а при обращении к массиву, происходит `Notice` - предупреждение, о том, что такой индекс не существует.

Comment: А чем отличается fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) и fetch_assoc()?